# clearInterval() not working in React Native - trying to convert from class to functional components - Timer

Tags: javascript, react-native, timer, react-hooks, setinterval

Trying to make a stopwatch in react native I have the **working code** with class components but when trying with functional components the `clearInterval()` function doesn't work

source code from ReactNativeAcademy/Stopwatch before modifications here https://github.com/ReactNativeAcademy/Stopwatch/blob/master/App.js

I need just a basic timer without laps with only **start**/**resume**/**stop**/**reset** buttons
snack url for my code: https://snack.expo.io/@mansouriala/nervous-mixed-nuts
in order to test it in class based components you can find each class based function commented under the functional one.

I don't know but maybe one solution for that could be to wrap setInterval in a useEffect then make a new state variable toggle it to true when start and the useEffect listens to that variable.

without further ado here's the code:

```
import React, { Component, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import moment from 'moment';

function Timer({ interval, style }) {
  const pad = (n) => (n < 10 ? `0${n}` : n);
  const duration = moment.duration(interval);
  const centiseconds = Math.floor(duration.milliseconds() / 10);

  return (
    <View style={styles.timerContainer}>
      <Text style={style}>{pad(duration.minutes())}:</Text>
      <Text style={style}>{pad(duration.seconds())},</Text>
      <Text style={style}>{pad(centiseconds)}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

function RoundButton({ title, color, background, onPress }) {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPress} style={[styles.button, { backgroundColor: background }]}>
      <View style={styles.buttonBorder}>
        <Text style={[styles.buttonTitle, { color }]}>{title}</Text>
      </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
}

function ButtonsRow({ children }) {
  return <View style={styles.buttonsRow}>{children}</View>;
}

// export default class App extends Component {
export default function App() {
  const [timer, setTimer] = useState(0);
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    start: 0,
    now: 0,
    currentTime: 0,
  });

  // constructor(props) {
  //   super(props);
  //   this.state = {
  //     start: 0,
  //     now: 0,
  //     currentTime: 0,
  //   };
  // }

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      clearInterval(timer);
    };
  }, []);

  // componentWillUnmount() {
  //   clearInterval(this.timer);
  // }

  const startHandler = () => {
    const now = new Date().getTime();
    setState({
      start: now,
      now,
      currentTime: 0,
    });
    setInterval(
      setInterval(() => {
        setState((prev) => ({ ...prev, now: new Date().getTime() }));
      }, 100)
    );
  };

  // startHandler = () => {
  //   const now = new Date().getTime();
  //   this.setState({
  //     start: now,
  //     now,
  //     currentTime: 0,
  //   });
  //   this.timer = setInterval(() => {
  //     this.setState({ now: new Date().getTime() });
  //   }, 100);
  // };

  const stopHandler = () => {
    clearInterval(timer);
    const { currentTime, now, start } = state;
    setState((prev) => ({
      // ...prev,
      currentTime: currentTime + (now - start),
      start: 0,
      now: 0,
    }));
  };

  // stopHandler = () => {
  //   clearInterval(this.timer);
  //   const { currentTime, now, start } = this.state;
  //   this.setState({
  //     currentTime: currentTime + now - start,
  //     start: 0,
  //     now: 0,
  //   });
  // };

  const resetHandler = () => {
    setState({
      currentTime: 0,
      start: 0,
      now: 0,
    });
  };

  // resetHandler = () => {
  //   this.setState({
  //     currentTime: 0,
  //     start: 0,
  //     now: 0,
  //   });
  // };

  const resumeHandler = () => {
    const now = new Date().getTime();
    setState({
      start: now,
      now,
    });
    setTimer(
      setInterval(() => {
        setState((prev) => ({ ...prev, now: new Date().getTime() }));
      }, 100)
    );
  };

  // resumeHandler = () => {
  //   const now = new Date().getTime();
  //   this.setState({
  //     start: now,
  //     now,
  //   });
  //   this.timer = setInterval(() => {
  //     this.setState({ now: new Date().getTime() });
  //   }, 100);
  // };

  // render() {
  const { now, start, currentTime } = state;
  // const { now, start, currentTime } = this.state;

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Timer interval={currentTime + (now - start)} style={styles.timer} />
      <ButtonsRow>
        <RoundButton title={'Start'} color={'#50D167'} background={'#1B361F'} onPress={startHandler} />
        <RoundButton title={'Stop'} color={'#E33935'} background={'#3C1715'} onPress={stopHandler} />
        <RoundButton title={'Reset'} color={'#FFFFFF'} background={'#3D3D3D'} onPress={resetHandler} />
        <RoundButton title={'Resume'} color={'#50D167'} background={'#1B361F'} onPress={resumeHandler} />
      </ButtonsRow>
    </View>
  );
}
// }

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#0D0D0D',
    alignItems: 'center',
    paddingTop: 130,
    paddingHorizontal: 20,
  },
  timer: {
    color: '#FFFFFF',
    fontSize: 76,
    fontWeight: '200',
    width: 110,
  },
  button: {
    width: 80,
    height: 80,
    borderRadius: 40,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  buttonTitle: {
    fontSize: 18,
  },
  buttonBorder: {
    width: 76,
    height: 76,
    borderRadius: 38,
    borderWidth: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  buttonsRow: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignSelf: 'stretch',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    marginTop: 80,
    marginBottom: 30,
  },
  timerContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it:

```
useEffect(() => {    
  clearInterval(timer);  
}, []);
```

When using **return** inside useEffect, the code is only triggered when component unmount.

Comment: Yep I've just tried it... thanks but it doesn't work actually we want to clearInterval onPress of Stop and  when the component is unmounted too but the problem is in the stopHandler function it doesn't clear the Interval

Comment: I've just saw you are using setInterval inside setInterval... I believe the problem is with setInterval, not clearInterval.

Comment: sorry where I'm doing this ??

Comment: Inside const startHandler.... setInterval is duplicated.

Comment: In the startHandler yeah found it instead of setTimer oh gosh what a mistake I always do the hard part and get caught with namings and typos thank you so much it's working now